# Making a custom list ADT instance of Monoid

Tags: haskell

It's probably something obvious I'm missing, but it seems like this should work, yet it gives an `Expecting one more argument to ‘Star' Expected a type, but ‘Star’ has kind ‘* -> *’` error, which I can't decipher.

```
data Star a = None | Union a (Star a)
    deriving Show

instance Monoid Star where
    mempty = None
    mappend None rs = rs
    mappend (Union r rs) rst = Union r (mappend rs rst)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only a concrete type (e.g. Int) can be a Monoid. Star is an abstract type with kind * -> *.
Edit: Of course (Star a) can also be a Monoid (like [a]), but not Star.

```
instance Monoid (Star a) where
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, got it. I had tried `Star a` before but didn't put the parentheses, so I got another mistake.